# Spivak Calculus vs Abbott

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

I have a copy of both Spivak calculus and Apostol.

I use both from time. However, I find some of Spivak's problems just boring. I was thinking of maybe trying Abbott.

Especially for continuity proofs, I want a book which **slowly,** progresses from easy to difficult proofs, because Spivak is very fast, and very difficult. Most of the time I cant do Spivak problems.

So should I give Abbott's Understanding Analysis, a try? Or is Spivak better?

Comment: Spivak is very fast?! He takes a detailed, intuitive step-by-step approach to define the notion of limit and hence of continuity. He takes seven pages to do so, and the first four of them contain pictures and diagrams.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, I phrased it incorrectly. Some of the examples he shows of proofs are **very easy** compared to the exercises. The exercises are really **really** difficult.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, proof of the squeeze theorem. It is an exercise in Chapter 5. I believe the proof is supposed to be by contradiction, and I had no idea how to let $h = g - f$

Comment: If you were able to show that $f(x)\leqslant g(x)\implies \lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)\leqslant \lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x)$, consider $f\leqslant g\leqslant h$. If you let $a=\lim\limits_{x\to a} f=\lim\limits_{x\to a} h,b=\lim\limits_{x\to a} g,$, the last consideration shows that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f = a\leqslant b =\lim\limits_{x\to a} g$, $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g =b\leqslant a = \lim\limits_{x\to a} h$, so the double inequality entails $a=b$.

Comment: Many exercises are like this: one carries into another, in increasing (or not?) difficulty. Personally, I would keep reading Spivak, and give it more time if necessary. You're always invited to drop by the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) and clear out any doubts or request help.

Comment: The exercises in Spivak are indeed tough, but isn't that the point? If you don't find an exercise hard, it isn't worth doing, and Spivak's are not unreasonably hard. 

I found his book to be very interesting and his problems have a good mix between routine practice and insightful problems, there is often a hint and always a tone of dry humour. 

Don't forget, you always have us here on SE to help you with them! If you want, I have typed my solutions to some of the harder problems and can send some to you if you message me in chat.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, thank you, I will indeed continue Spivak.